Some users' Android devices, location information does not update when they enter lockscreen; it updates again when they turn the screen on
I'm using Flutter, I'm using Geolocator.stream for the location stream, and I'm also using ForegroundService so that the location transport is always maintained.
However, on some real users' devices, sometimes when the phone enters the lock screen, the location information is not updated. When the screen is turned on again after a few minutes (even if the screen is turned on because of an incoming call), the location information is updated again.
Location permission is Always, and Power Saving Mode is also off.
This doesn't always happen on the same device...
I can't even reproduce it on my test device :(
Is there a workaround...?
Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

AndroidManifest.xml
